# Feller condition for CIR process positivity

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

I am trying to understand Feller’s square root condition which provides the existence of the positive solution of the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross which introduced by Gikhman, Ilya

please find link to the note [feller_condition](https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=484029088111003006075096089001125072016089038039060053007118008027101109086071092109010114056102019017037120126028072093005115048032033082076106114096122090099026050019094092068124083081118113070085113006090121097088109010027086008074026064078066113&EXT=pdf)

what I don't really understand is how he deal with the stochastic term in the following context

$$v^{-n} (T_\varepsilon \wedge t) = v^{-n}(0) +\int_0^{T_\varepsilon \wedge t}n\kappa(v(s) - \gamma)v^{-(n+1)} (s)ds
-\int_0^{T_\varepsilon \wedge t}n\eta \sqrt{v(s)}v^{-(n+1)}(s)dW_s\\
+ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{T_\varepsilon \wedge t}n(n+1)\eta^2v(s)v^{-(n+2)} (s)d s$$
$$=v^{-n}(0) + n\kappa \int_0^t v^{-n}(T_\varepsilon \wedge s)ds -\int_0^t n\eta v^{-(n+1/2)} (T_\varepsilon \wedge s)dW_s
+\int_0^t[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\eta^2-n\kappa \gamma]v^{-(n+1)}(T_\varepsilon \wedge s)ds$$.

Then he end up by saying taking expectation in the latter equality, we arrive at the estimate

$$\mathbb{E}[v^{-n} (T_\varepsilon \wedge t)] \leq v^{-n}(0) + n\kappa \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[v^{-n}(T_\varepsilon \wedge s)]ds.$$

so my question here where the stochastic term disappears, it seems he deal with it as a positive term which yields the last estimate but I don't understand why or if there is any other explanation to it?!

any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: My best guess would be that the stochastic integral is a martingale, so the expectation is zero. For the second deterministic integral, do you have any conditions that ensures $n(n+1)/2\eta^2-n\kappa\gamma<0$?

Comment: the deterministic part is clear and doable. But the stochastic term is not. I don't think it is zero as it is multiplicative noise. In addition if it is indeed zero how the inequality appears in the picture! it will be equal

Comment: Whether or not the stochastic integral is a martingale does not depend on the noise being multiplicative or not. As long as the integrant is measurable w.r.t to some filtration and the integrant is square integrable, the expectation is really zero. Then, the fact that you discard the last integral gives the inequality.

Comment: Ok, I understand now thank you. Can you please give me any reference!

Comment: You will find this in any textbook on stochastic integration theory. The whole point of the Ito integral is that it is a martingale, so you can surely find it in your preferred book.